# get waveform data with Visualizer class in android

Tags: android, waveform, visualizer

I need waveform data like a matrix or array 
How can i receive waveform data with [visualizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer) class when a music is playing in android ?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer ... Terrific project.

Comment: can you give me a sample code ?

Comment: That github project is a the sample.  It should have everything, you can cut & paste. This is the demo app main src page: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/app/MainActivity.java the workarounds https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/tree/master/src/com/pheelicks/utils and the visualizer / rendered stuff https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/tree/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer which have like no code hardly at all. I'd throw all the files in one directory and start by opening mainactivity.java.

Comment: I found this : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-integrate-audio-visualizer-with-your-androi Possibly, more straight-forward?